# Direction of angular velocity vector VS angular momentum vector

Tags: angular-momentum, inertial-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity, precession

I understand that angular velocity and angular momentum velocities don’t need to be parallel to each other. However, I’m confused what these vectors even represent. So I have 3 questions about this:

1. What does it mean for a rigid body to have a 3D angular velocity vector at a certain point? Does it mean that the rigid body rotates around the vector in counter-clockwise, and the origin of the angular velocity vector is stationary (not rotating) in the body-fixed frame?
2. If the angular velocity vector is used to describe the rotation direction of the rigid body, what does the angular momentum vector point towards?
3. If the rigid body is precessing, is the angular velocity vector fixed in the rigid body’s body-fixed frame, which describes the body-fixed rotation direction of the body? Is the angular momentum velocity momentum vector fixed in the inertial frame and describing the rotation of the precession from the inertial frame?

I apologize for the overload of questions. Please let me know if they are confusing.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this an overload of questions.

Recommendation: look up information about the case that is known as 'Feynman's wobbling plate'. It's pretty much the simplest case where the angular velocity vector and the angular momentum vector do not coincide.

Feynman's wobbling plate is a continuous motion pattern. That is: in the absense of air friction the motion pattern will continue indefinitely.

The wobbling is a continuous process of internal relocation of momentum. The instantaneous angular velocity vector is the vector that is perpendicular to the instantaneous plane of rotation. The parts of the plate are themselves not moving in a plane, the *instantaneous* plane of rotation is the plane that is tangent to the instantaneous direction of motion of the plate parts.

The angular velocity vector sweeps out a cone around the angular momentum vector.

Youtube video with 40 second simulation:
[Feynman's wobbling plate, in space frame and body frame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZcnkHaKzSg)

In the process of wobbling there are internal stresses, these are the forces of the momentum relocation process. If the plate would be flexible it would flex all the time, and that flexing would dissipate kinetic energy.

At the opposite of the rigidity of a plate is the pizza dough that we see in the art of throwing a spinning slab of pizza dough in the air to make it stretch. You never see any wobbling of that slab of pizza dough. If the pizza maker inadvertendly imparts some wobble then the kinetic energy accociated with that wobble is dissipated almost immediately; the dough just deforms.

Comment: Thank you very much!